# log4j2 accessing env properties

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

The log4j2 documents mentioned to read the env property we must use `$${env:USERNAME}`

I found that `${env:USERNAME}` with single `$` is still working.

Does any one knows why should we use `$$`?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html manual page:

> An interesting feature of StrLookup processing is that when a variable
>   reference is declared with multiple leading '$' characters each time
>   the variable is resolved the leading '$' is simply removed. In the
>   previous example the "Routes" element is capable of resolving the
>   variable at runtime. To allow this the prefix value is specified as a
>   variable with two leading '$' characters. When the configuration file
>   is first processed the first variable is simply removed. Thus, when
>   the Routes element is evaluated at runtime it is the variable
>   declaration "${sd:type}" which causes the event to be inspected for a
>   StructuredDataMessage and if one is present the value of its type
>   attribute to be used as the routing key. Not all elements support
>   resolving variables at runtime. Components that do will specifically
>   call that out in their documentation.